# How to import a .bas file in excel for mac 2016

Tags: excel, macos, excel-2016

I wrote some macro's in excel for mac 2011 and/or regular excel, and saved them as .bas files. However company policy pushed excel for mac 2016, and since then I can no longer import previously written VBA code, saved as .bas file, into my workbook. Anyone that knows a fix or work around other then reverting back to 2011 version of excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to import .bas files with version 2016 Excel for Mac 16.9, which was released last week. I don't know what you had trouble with at the time of writing, but it works now by right-clicking in the VBA Project area, the selecting "Import File..." .

[image: ImportFileExample]

Comment: Yes figured that out yesterday as well. I was subscribed to the developper program, so at the time I was working with the most recent version.